# Change TMP/TEMP variables for a Domain Service Account

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2

I want to change the TMP and TEMP variables for a Domain Service Account

Normally, for local users I can change this variable via regedit > HKEY_USERS > SID number of account

But for the Domain Service Account I can't find the Sid number in HKEY_USERS.

How can I change these variables for such an account?

Answer (score 0):

You could use group policy preferences with item level targeting for that user. This can change those variables for a specific user.

In GPMC, the environment variables are under User->preferences->windows settings->Environment.